# Disqus API - Post -> What does highlight do?

Tags: post, highlighting, disqus

I'm currently comparing commenting systems and try to find out which comment system allows anything close to "editors picks" - that is admins can flag a post/comment as valuable and once a discussion is closed the valuable posts can be fetched via API.

So far the only system that seems to do it is disqus though it seems to be not clear because I find no explanations for the following method: http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/highlight/

Does anybody know what exactly highlighting in disqus means?

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting was a feature a sort order in the embed; it allowed moderators to highlight certain comments. It has been deprecated in favor of more organic discovery systems, namely the Best Rating and Popular Now sort orders. The API endpoint still exists as a legacy method for backwards compatibility.