# Is there anyway to "highlight" a post without using the API?

Tags: disqus

It seems like just the feature we need to be able to select a few favorite posts ourselves but I cannot find any highlight buttons on the posts in any of the moderation UIs.

I guess this is a related question: [Disqus API - Post -> What does highlight do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135808/disqus-api-post-what-does-highlight-do) but I'm more curious about where that button could be.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting as a feature (it was a sort order in the embed) has been deprecated in favor of more organic discovery systems, namely the Best Rating and Popular Now sort orders. There is no longer a way to manually highlight posts.

To elaborate, highlighting as an API endpoint is actually a legacy endpoint kept around for backwards compatibility. Even if you were to highlight posts using that endpoint they would not show up as such in the embed since the sort order has been deprecated.

Comment: but would we still be able to filter on them?

Comment: @RobertSköld Yup, via the isHighlighted param in the response.